# CakePHP 3.x JOIN query using 2 databases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an application in CakePHP 3.4.6. It is interacting with 3 legacy databases - that is to say databases which have not been written according to CakePHP naming conventions.

I have configured connections to these databases in `config/app.php`:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'substances_db'
    ],
    'org_data' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'organisation_data_db'
    ],
    ...
]
```

I need to be able to write a query which selects data from the "default" database (`substances_db`) and does a `JOIN` with data in the "org_db" database (`organisation_data_db`).

I am not using Cake's ORM for any part of the application, because there are so many tables that are written contrary to Cake's conventions.

The way I have done things is as per Cake's documentation on [Database Basics - Executing Queries](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#executing-queries).

For example, in `src/Model/SubstanceModel.php` I get the connections to each database so I can use them in my model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class SubstanceModel
{

    protected $db_default;
    protected $db_orgs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db_default = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $this->db_orgs = ConnectionManager::get('org_data');
    }
 }
```

This means that I can write queries inside model functions, e.g.

```
public function getTotalSubstances()
{ 
    // Executes query on "default" database ('substances_db')

    $results = $this->db_default->execute('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) AS total_substances FROM substances')->fetch('assoc');
    return (int)$results['total_substances'];
}
```

All of this works fine.

But I now need to write a query which does a `JOIN` to some of the tables in `organisation_data_db`.

I don't know how to do this. The MySQL equivalent is where you would prefix the names of the databases to the tables in a query, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM substances_db.table1 JOIN organisation_data_db.table2 ...
```

Is this possible in CakePHP 3.x?

Comment: Well, I'd say, give it a try!?

Comment: I have a lot of respect for you @ndm as you've given good answers before. However, you'll notice that when executing a query it's using `$this->db_default->execute`. This is a connection to the "substances_db" database. That isn't going to work if I need to make a connection to the secondary database, "organisation_data_db", as defined in `config/app.php`

Comment: The connections look similar to me, it's the same server, and MySQL supports cross database joins as long as the current user has permissions to access all the involved databases/tables, so from the details provided (If there's further details other than Cross DB join on MySQL, please provide them), there's nothing that should prevent this from working, hence I'd again suggest to give it a try and see what happens. If there's an error, please show it, it may give a hint about what the problem might be.